# Trouble with Computer Systems 2 Midterm Study Guide

Tags: c

So this is a question we got on our study guide:

A friend wants to write a program with a parent and a child process that allows the parent to count events in the child. The idea is that the child sends a signal (SIGUSR2) to the parent at each event. The parent has a signal handler for SIGUSR2 that increments a counter each time the handler executes. The parent can then print the count after the child has terminated.

Your friend tried to write a prototype below. The child sends 5 signals to the parent. Your friend tried it with the calls to sleep at lines 6 and 20 to simulate work by the parent and work by the child. He expected the counter value printed at line 27 to be 5.

However, with the sleep times as below, he consistently got the value 1 printed, not 5.

He asks you why he got 1, not 5. What is your explanation?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


1   int counter = 0;
2   
3   void handler(int sig) 
4   {
5       counter++;
6       sleep(1); /* Parent does some work in the handler */
7       return;
8   }
9   
10  int main() 
11  {
12      int i;
13  
14      signal(SIGUSR2, handler);
15  
16      if (fork() == 0) {  /* Child */
17      for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
18          kill(getppid(), SIGUSR2);
19          printf("sent SIGUSR2 to parent\n");
20          sleep(1); /* Child does some work */
21    
22      }
23      exit(0);
24      }
25  
26      waitpid(-1, NULL, 0);
27      printf("counter=%d\n", counter); 
28      exit(0);
29  }
```

It looked correct to me, and when I took the code and ran it, the output it gave me was 5. So I guess my question is is there something I'm not seeing or is this a typo? I emailed my prof a couple hours ago and have still heard nothing

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear from your description which process had which sleep-time, but if the parent's time is longer than the child's, then the child may terminate before the parent has had a chance to process all of the signals.  Consider the extreme case where the parent goes to sleep after the first signal is caught so long that the child exits before the parent wakes up; it will never see any signal after the first.